# Print From Apps (UWP)

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

I want to ask on how to print our own content. Example like we have some forms and after submitting the form, the details go to Page To Print. And then print.

I used the example from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Printing/cs.

But when i tried to print my content, the page turn to empty page.

I am new to the windows phone development and c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) contains a lot of complex features for print. Directly replace some contents of the sample may not be work well. I have a sample demo here which can meet print requirements. And just replace the content inside `PrintArea` Grid to your own's, the sample can print your content.

XAML Code

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="appbar_Printer"
                      Click="appbar_Printer_Click"
                      Label="printer">       
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="White" x:Name="PrintArea" >
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="36"
               Foreground="Black"
               Text="Welcome Printed World!" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
  PrintManager printmgr = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();        
  PrintDocument printDoc = null;         
  PrintTask task = null; 
  public MainPage()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent(); 
      printmgr.PrintTaskRequested += Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
  }
  private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
  {  
      var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral(); 
      task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Print", OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested);
      //task.Completed += PrintTask_Completed;
      PrintTaskOptionDetails printDetailedOptions = PrintTaskOptionDetails.GetFromPrintTaskOptions(task.Options);    
      deferral.Complete();
  } 
  //private void PrintTask_Completed(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
  //{
  //    //Completed
  //}
  private async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
  {
      var def = args.GetDeferral();
      await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        { 
            args.SetSource(printDoc?.DocumentSource);
        });
      def.Complete();
  }
  private async void appbar_Printer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (printDoc != null)
      {
          printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= OnGetPreviewPage;
          printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDic_Paginate;
          printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDic_AddPages;
      }
      this.printDoc = new PrintDocument();          
      printDoc.GetPreviewPage += OnGetPreviewPage;        
      printDoc.Paginate += PrintDic_Paginate;   
      printDoc.AddPages += PrintDic_AddPages;        
      bool showPrint = await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
  }     
  private void PrintDic_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
  { 
      printDoc.AddPage(this);
      printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
  }       
  private void PrintDic_Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
  {
      PrintTaskOptions opt = task.Options;
      PrintTaskOptionDetails printDetailedOptions = PrintTaskOptionDetails.GetFromPrintTaskOptions(e.PrintTaskOptions);
      printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
  }
  private void OnGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
  {
        printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, PrintArea); 
  }
```

If you have more requirements, for example, require more [print options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.printing.printtask.options), please reference the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app#prepare-print-options) as well as the official sample.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just like what im looking for. :)